# TableView not loading when tapped with Tab Bar Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

When transitioning from the details tab to the tags tab, the table view is not loading.  I know because in the view did load I had it print a comment but the comment and the rest of the code is running or loading.  Even though the table view itself is appearing.  Sorry if this is too vague , I'm not sure what I need to provide so please let me know if you need more info to help me[image: bo]

Comment: provide your code ? are you getting data from API ?

Comment: @jawadAli Yes I am using data from an API, it's a lot of code.  What would be the best way for me to display it to you and the others :?

Comment: Just copy paste relevant code as a [example] in your question. Don't use screenshots - they are difficult to read. See also [ask].

Comment: are you using any kind of animations on that tab?

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a `tab` it's loaded and maintained in memory. It doesn't require to be reloaded. If you want to load the data again move the data loading code to `viewDidAppear` like this:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        loadData()
    }

    func loadData() {
        // Code to load data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you get data from Api reload your tableView `tableview.reloadData()` there on Main thread using `DisaptchQueue.main.async {}`

```
// got response from Api
DisaptchQueue.main.async {
tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Okay , I think I misunderstood the question from before.  I run and obtain data from the api in the first table view, and then I save it to the database.  when I click on the cell from the first Table view, it should take me to the other two views and display the data by reading the data base.  But for some reason in the table view , the view seems to not be loading or anything.  None of the data is displaying.  I made sure to have a data reload function and the reload data function.

Comment: so in next view .. you are getting data from database ? how tableView send data to next view ?

Comment: yes I have a function that reads the database, then populates the reusable cell.  But it seems like the view and nothing in it is "loading"